# Wordpress plugin to authenticate Facebook users after approval

Tags: wordpress, facebook, authentication

Wordpress site which you can use with Facebook account after approval. What plugins do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question sprung very little interest I'm trying ot answer it by myself. I've found a plugin named "Nextend social login". It's documentation is somewhat vague on behalf of the registration part, but it looks like or seems to have this desired functionality in the PRO version.